# Input array and different output after using PorterStemmer in php

Tags: php, foreach, porter-stemmer

I'm using PorterStemmer to stem words just like "working" it will be "work" after calling PorterStemmer class, and it worked for me.

But I want to stem a sentence, for example if I give this sentence to my code:

**Before**

"I'm playing football and working hard because I have powerful enough"

**After**

"I'm play football and work hard because I have power enough"

It seems that I have problem with using "foreach" loop in php, because my code is stemming just one word.

My code:

```
$str=('I am playing football and working hard because I have powerful enough');
$parts = explode(' ', $str);

$word_to_stem = $str;
$stem = PorterStemmer::Stem($word_to_stem);
```

Now, the `$parts` included my sentence as an array, how can I stem every word and after that put the new sentence in new variable called `$str2`

Comment: And where is `foreach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to stem every word:

```
$str=('I am playing football and working hard because I have powerful enough');
$parts = explode(' ', $str);
$stemmed_parts = array();

foreach ($parts as $word) {
    $stemmed_word = PorterStemmer::Stem($word);
    $stemmed_parts[] = $stemmed_word;
}

echo implode(' ', $stemmed_parts);
```